# Calculating percentile conditional on continuous variable

Tags: quantiles, conditioning

I have a collection of datasets with (x,y) - pairs where the value of y is conditional on x. Neither the distribution of x nor of y is known, n is ranging from 1000 to 10000. Here is the scatterplot for one of the sets.

[image: example scatterplot of x,y]

Now I want to calculate the percentiles of y conditional on x, so basically a function mapping x to the e.g. 80th percentile.

My thoughts on this subject:

- To control the variance the percentiles should be calculated on a minimum number of values (e.g. 100, does a rule of the thumb exists for this ?)
- This lead to the idea to discretize x with equal-width-bins, but a smoother curve is more desirable
- Which lead to kernel-functions as used in density estimation, but the formula is not directly applicable to percentile estimation (as far as I see)
- I had a look at Bayesian Networks, but I do not know the distribution of x or y and I am reluctant to make any assumptions here.

At this point I was pretty sure that a standard solution must exist for this kind of problem, for example when it comes to plotting certain properties of y given x (both continuous). So ... what is the common approach here ? Does this problem / method have a name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression). In its simplest form your 80th percentile will change linearly with $x$, but there are various ways to make that more flexible. The simplest of those would be to add splines or polynomials of $x$, but I am sure there are also more formal non(less)-parametric estimators in that family.

Comment: Sometime one cannot see the forest for the trees. Thank you for lightning a candle and getting this wanderer back on track :)

Comment: +1 At least as a starting point, quantile regression makes a lot of sense.